# How to figure out if Variant contains certain text + number in format text###

Tags: vba, excel, powerpoint

I am having some trouble identifying whether a Variant/String stored in `iq_Array` is in the format I would like it to be. I want my code to execute only if `iq_Array = iq_###` with `iq_###` meaning that it must include the words `iq_` and must be followed by one, two, or three numbers. All these are fine:

1. `iq_9`
2. `iq_99`
3. `iq_999`

But there are not:

1. `iq_9,` or `iq_9999`
2. `iq_23,iq_5`
3. `iq_`
4. `iq _3`

Any help here would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use a wildcard `#`(numerical wildcard) like this:

```
if iq_Array(i) like "iq_#" Or iq_Array(i) like "iq_##" or iq_Array(i) like "iq_###" then
    ... code ....
end if
```

if iq_Array is not string you probably can wrap it in `Cstr`: `Cstr(iq_Array(i))`

Comment: I love this idea... but this gives me a compile error unfortunately. It highlights the second `like` and says Expected: expression

Comment: need to add the iq_Array(i) in front of each like.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [Split Function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/6x627e5f(v=vs.90).aspx)

#### Extract Element Function

```
Function EXTRACTELEMENT(Txt As String, n, Separator As String) As String
 EXTRACTELEMENT = Split(Application.Trim(Txt), Separator)(n - 1)
End Function
```

#### Code

If ele1 or ele2 of an coll of the collection is NOK, then that coll is Not OK, otherwise, it is OK

```
Dim coll As Collection
Dim i As Long
Dim stemp As String, ele1 As String, ele2 As String

Set coll = New Collection
coll.Add "iq_9"
coll.Add "iq_99"
coll.Add "iq_999"
coll.Add "iq_9,"
coll.Add "iq_23,iq_5"
coll.Add "iq_"
coll.Add "iq _3"

If coll.Count > 0 Then
    For i = 1 To coll.Count
        stemp = stemp & coll(i) & ";"
        ele1 = EXTRACTELEMENT(coll(i), 1, "_")
        ele2 = EXTRACTELEMENT(coll(i), 2, "_")
        valueprint = valueprint & vbNewLine & coll(i) & " ele1: " & ele1 & " ele2: " & ele2 'For Debugging test
        If ele1 = "iq" Then
            Debug.Print vbNewLine & coll(i) & "Ele1 OK"
        Else
            Debug.Print vbNewLine & coll(i) & "Ele1 NOK"
        End If
        If IsNumeric(ele2) = True And InStr(1, ele2, ",") = 0 Then
            Debug.Print vbNewLine & coll(i) & "Ele2 OK"
        Else
            Debug.Print vbNewLine & coll(i) & "Ele2 NOK"
        End If
    Next i

Debug.Print stemp & valueprint

End If

Set coll = Nothing
```

#### Optional, description of the UDF EXTRACELEMENT

```
Sub DescribeFunction()
   Dim FuncName As String
   Dim FuncDesc As String
   Dim Category As String
   Dim ArgDesc(1 To 3) As String

   FuncName = "EXTRACTELEMENT"
   FuncDesc = "Returns the nth element of a string that uses a separator character/Retorna o enésimo elemento da string que usa um caractér separador."
   Category = 7 'Text category
   ArgDesc(1) = "String that contains the elements/String que contém o elemento"
   ArgDesc(2) = "Element number to return/ Número do elemento a retornar"
   ArgDesc(3) = "Single-character element separator/ Elemento único separador (spc por padrão)"

   Application.MacroOptions _
      Macro:=FuncName, _
      Description:=FuncDesc, _
      Category:=Category, _
      ArgumentDescriptions:=ArgDesc
End Sub
```

Comment: Valeus pelas duas opicoes! Eu acho que o jeito mais "rapido" e de usar o truque que o Victor K escreveu ali em cima, mais pra falar a verdade eu nao entendi muito bem o que que e este segundo codigo seu, o EXTRACTELEMENT?

Comment: @Pinlop É uma UDF, função definida para usuário, ou seja, cria uma função customizada. Em que a função Split é utilizada. você pode usar esta função nas células da planilha também, em que você insere  EXTRACTELEMENT(Texto, número do elemento, Separador) e o último código é a descrição da função quando você insere a mesma. Exemplo.: 1 a 3 na célula A1, com a função `EXTRACTELEMENT("A1",1," ")` a resposta é 1 e para `EXTRACTELEMENT("A1",2," ")` a resposta é a. Porque o espaço é usado como separador " "

Comment: Entendido! Valeu pela ajuda :) @danieltakeshi